# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: No address is available

Tags: jax-ws, stateful

I have a stateful WebService and a stateless one, which returns a EndPointReference to a new Instance of the stateful webservice. Like the example in this blog https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/10/stateful_web_se.html

```
@Stateful
@WebService
@Addressing
class BankAccount {
protected final int id;
private int balance;

public BankAccount(int id) { this.id = id; }

@WebMethod
public void deposit(int amount) { balance+=amount; }

// either via a public static field

public static StatefulWebServiceManager<BankAccount> manager;
}
```

..

```
@WebService
class Bank { // this is ordinary stateless service
    @WebMethod
    public synchronized W3CEndpointReference login(int accountId) {
          BankAccount acc = new BankAccount(accountId);
          return BankAccount.manager.export(acc);
    }
}
```

But when I run the client and call the stateless service method "login" I get following Exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: No address is available for {http://server.stateful
/}BankAccountPort
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the JAX-WS runtime? JAX-WS RI or CXF or Axis2? What are you using as Application Server? Tomcat or Glassfish or Websphere?